# Intelli J Maven "Failed to read artifact descriptor ..." when importing project

Tags: maven, intellij-idea

When importing a Maven project into Intelli J:

> file > open > select pom.xml

From here I allowed auto importing for maven and allowed Intelli J to index and resolve dependencies. However, the project did not compile. Hovering over the Maven project view says:

> "Failed to read artifact descriptor ..."

- I have used an installed maven distro and a Intelli J bundled maven distro.
- The best "fix" which compiles the code is:

`mvn -U idea:idea`

Which installs a retied plugin, however the code compiles and the dependencies show in the project view, but I still get the "Failed to read artifact descriptor ..." error in the maven  projects view.

Additional Info

1. This project uses:

`<shared-libs-repo> scpexe:// ... </shared-libs-repo>`

in the settings.xml file, when running `mvn compile`, there appears to be no issue as all dependencies are downloaded, but this is not reflected in the IDE.

> ("Failed to read artifact descriptor ...")

2. When deleting all of the dependencies in ~/.m2/repository/
   and then re-importing the dependencies in Intelli J, dependiencies are downloaded, but again not reflected in the IDE. ("Failed to read artifact descriptor ...")
3. Restarting and clearing the cache does not help.
4. This project imports correctly on Mac and Windows, but Linux appears to be an issue.
5. Project does not import on Eclipse either
6. Intelli J also says that dependencies have been:

> omitted for duplicate

7. Intelli J logs

```java
2017-04-24 17:37:27,401 [ 136169]   INFO -      #org.jetbrains.idea.maven - [WARNING] Could not transfer metadata org.luaj:luaj-jse:3.0.2-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml from/to shared-libs (scpexe://mvn.stb.hexcode.co.za/maven): Cannot access scpexe://mvn.stb.hexcode.co.za/maven with type default using the available connector factories: BasicRepositoryConnectorFactory 
2017-04-24 17:37:27,403 [ 136171]   INFO -      #org.jetbrains.idea.maven - [WARNING] Failure to transfer org.luaj:luaj-jse:3.0.2-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml from scpexe://mvn.stb.hexcode.co.za/maven was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of shared-libs has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer metadata org.luaj:luaj-jse:3.0.2-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml from/to shared-libs (scpexe://mvn.stb.hexcode.co.za/maven): Cannot access scpexe://mvn.stb.hexcode.co.za/maven with type default using the available connector factories: BasicRepositoryConnectorFactory 
2017-04-24 17:37:27,753 [ 136521]   INFO -      #org.jetbrains.idea.maven - org.eclipse.aether.resolution.ArtifactDescriptorException: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.luaj:luaj-jse:jar:3.0.2-SNAPSHOT 
java.lang.RuntimeException: org.eclipse.aether.resolution.ArtifactDescriptorException: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.luaj:luaj-jse:jar:3.0.2-SNAPSHOT
    at org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.loadPom(DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.java:282)
    at org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.readArtifactDescriptor(DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.java:198)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.resolveCachedArtifactDescriptor(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:535)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.getArtifactDescriptorResult(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:519)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.processDependency(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:409)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.processDependency(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:363)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.process(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:351)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.doRecurse(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:504)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.processDependency(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:458)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.processDependency(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:363)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.process(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:351)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.collectDependencies(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:254)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultRepositorySystem.collectDependencies(DefaultRepositorySystem.java:316)
    at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectDependenciesResolver.resolve(DefaultProjectDependenciesResolver.java:172)
    at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.server.Maven3ServerEmbedderImpl.resolveDependencies(Maven3ServerEmbedderImpl.java:751)
    at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.server.Maven3ServerEmbedderImpl.access$600(Maven3ServerEmbedderImpl.java:121)
    at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.server.Maven3ServerEmbedderImpl$3.run(Maven3ServerEmbedderImpl.java:685)
    at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.server.Maven3ServerEmbedderImpl.executeWithMavenSession(Maven3ServerEmbedderImpl.java:621)
    at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.server.Maven3ServerEmbedderImpl.doResolveProject(Maven3ServerEmbedderImpl.java:640)
    at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.server.Maven3ServerEmbedderImpl.resolveProject(Maven3ServerEmbedderImpl.java:574)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:324)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:568)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:826)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(TCPTransport.java:683)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:682)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.eclipse.aether.resolution.ArtifactResolutionException: Could not transfer artifact org.luaj:luaj-jse:pom:3.0.2-SNAPSHOT from/to shared-libs (scpexe://mvn.stb.hexcode.co.za/maven): Cannot access scpexe://mvn.stb.hexcode.co.za/maven with type default using the available connector factories: BasicRepositoryConnectorFactory
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:444)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifacts(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:246)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifact(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:223)
    at org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.loadPom(DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.java:267)
    ... 36 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.eclipse.aether.transfer.ArtifactTransferException: Could not transfer artifact org.luaj:luaj-jse:pom:3.0.2-SNAPSHOT from/to shared-libs (scpexe://mvn.stb.hexcode.co.za/maven): Cannot access scpexe://mvn.stb.hexcode.co.za/maven with type default using the available connector factories: BasicRepositoryConnectorFactory
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.performDownloads(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:531)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:421)
    ... 39 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.eclipse.aether.transfer.NoRepositoryConnectorException: Cannot access scpexe://mvn.stb.hexcode.co.za/maven with type default using the available connector factories: BasicRepositoryConnectorFactory
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultRepositoryConnectorProvider.newRepositoryConnector(DefaultRepositoryConnectorProvider.java:174)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.performDownloads(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:516)
    ... 40 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.eclipse.aether.transfer.NoRepositoryConnectorException: Cannot access scpexe://mvn.stb.hexcode.co.za/maven using the registered transporter factories: WagonTransporterFactory
    at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector.<init>(BasicRepositoryConnector.java:119)
    at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnectorFactory.newInstance(BasicRepositoryConnectorFactory.java:180)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultRepositoryConnectorProvider.newRepositoryConnector(DefaultRepositoryConnectorProvider.java:113)
    ... 41 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.eclipse.aether.transfer.NoTransporterException: Cannot access scpexe://mvn.stb.hexcode.co.za/maven using the registered transporter factories: WagonTransporterFactory
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultTransporterProvider.newTransporter(DefaultTransporterProvider.java:151)
    at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector.<init>(BasicRepositoryConnector.java:115)
    ... 43 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.eclipse.aether.transfer.NoTransporterException: java.util.NoSuchElementException
      role: org.apache.maven.wagon.Wagon
  roleHint: scpexe
    at org.eclipse.aether.transport.wagon.WagonTransporter.<init>(WagonTransporter.java:120)
    at org.eclipse.aether.transport.wagon.WagonTransporterFactory.newInstance(WagonTransporterFactory.java:127)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultTransporterProvider.newTransporter(DefaultTransporterProvider.java:110)
    ... 44 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.codehaus.plexus.component.repository.exception.ComponentLookupException: java.util.NoSuchElementException
      role: org.apache.maven.wagon.Wagon
  roleHint: scpexe
    at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.lookup(DefaultPlexusContainer.java:267)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.lookup(DefaultPlexusContainer.java:255)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.transport.wagon.PlexusWagonProvider.lookup(PlexusWagonProvider.java:58)
    at org.eclipse.aether.transport.wagon.WagonTransporter.lookupWagon(WagonTransporter.java:271)
    at org.eclipse.aether.transport.wagon.WagonTransporter.<init>(WagonTransporter.java:115)
    ... 46 more
Caused by: java.util.NoSuchElementException
    at org.eclipse.sisu.plexus.RealmFilteredBeans$FilteredItr.next(RealmFilteredBeans.java:118)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.plexus.RealmFilteredBeans$FilteredItr.next(RealmFilteredBeans.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.plexus.DefaultPlexusBeans$Itr.next(DefaultPlexusBeans.java:76)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.plexus.DefaultPlexusBeans$Itr.next(DefaultPlexusBeans.java:1)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.lookup(DefaultPlexusContainer.java:263)
    ... 50 more
```

Comment: Check [idea.log](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/articles/207241085) for the details what exactly fails on import.

Comment: @CrazyCoder could  this be related to the wagon-ssh dependency? Intelli J throws a NoSuchElementException when consulting the WagonTransporter